# SQL conditioned

Tags: sql

I have this sql:

```
Select 
    t1.field01, 
    t1.field02, 
    t2.name02, 
    t2.surname02, 
from 
    lib01/FirstFile as t1, 
    lib02/SecondFile (lib02/ThirdFile) as t2 
where 
    t1.field01 = t2.field02 (or t3.filed02)
```

I need to have the condition that `if t1.field02 is equal to "AX"` I have to read the second file (lib02/SecondFile), `if t1.field02 is equal to "BX"` I have to read by the third file (lib02/ThirdFile).

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? And you should really stop using those ancient, outdated and fragile implicit joins in the where clause and use explicit `JOIN` operators instead

Answer (score 0):

```
Select      
    CASE 
       WHEN ((Select t1.field02 from lib01/FirstFile as t1 ) = AX)
           THEN Select t2.name02, t2.surname02 
                from lib02/SecondFile (lib02/ThirdFile) as t2 
    CASE 
       WHEN ((Select t1.field02 from lib01/FirstFile as t1 ) = BX)
          THEN Select t3.name02, t3.surname02 
               from (lib02/ThirdFile) as t3
    END
```

Change the code after each `THEN` clause if that retrieve is not what you want, but that is the logic.

And try to avoid use old syntax for `join`